# Specifying criteria as named range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula which is working properly:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(
dataExport.csv!$A:$A, {"itm1","itm2"},
dataExport.csv!$C:$C, [@[TheName]]
))
```

Is there a way to use the array part of the criteria in this line as a named range?:

`dataExport.csv!$A:$A, {"itm1","itm2"},`

If I had a named range – "itms" – which  consisted of two cells with values "itm1" and "itm2", would there be a way to refer to it? I realize the array is a constant, and cannot take references, but is there another way to do it?

`dataExport.csv!$A:$A, ** matches any value from "itms" **,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I enter `=SUM(COUNTIFS($A:$A,itms,$C:$C,[@TheName]))` as an array formula `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER` the named range works.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make some basic changes then you may be able to use FILTERXML to generate the array in the named range. I used a named range called namedRange in cell E1 which contains a comma separated list of the conditions.

D1 contains the following entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(
$A:$A, FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(namedRange,CHAR(44), "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"),
$C:$C,"Bob"
))
```

I have substituted my own values in.

[image]